# Why can't see image path?

Tags: python, image

why this function return **False** although the image already exists in that path and I wrote its name correctly

```
import cv2
import os
print(os.path.isfile('../Project/mark-zuker.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is probably run from another directory. If you have those statements in a script, try with the absolute path:

```
code_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_img = os.path.dirname(code_dir) + '/Project/mark-zuker.png'
print(file_img)
print(os.path.isfile(file_img))
```